how to add captha to login in SharePoint using NTLM?
I'm not sure if this is possible, but can we add that captcha when using NTLM authentication? I know that we can use form based and add that captcha in login page, but seeing that NTML doesn't have that customize login page dialog, can we add that?
We want to add to captcha because our SharePoint Server 2019 was getting hit with a lot login attempt which I think was coming from brute force program that was trying to get in.
Thanks.

Adding a CAPTCHA to NTLM authentication in SharePoint Server 2019 is tricky because NTLM (Windows Authentication) does not have a customizable login page like forms-based authentication does. However, there are a few approaches you could consider to protect your SharePoint Server from brute-force attacks:

Account Lockout Policies: Account lockout policies within Group Policy Management in your Active Directory (AD) can be set to lock user accounts after a certain number of failed login attempts, and reduce the effectiveness of brute-force attacks.

CAPTCHA with Forms-Based Authentication (FBA): Modify the SignIn.aspx page to add a CAPTCHA control, like Google reCAPTCHA.

Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)

Web Application Firewall (WAF): Use a Web Application Firewall in front of your SharePoint Server. WAFs can help mitigate brute-force login attempts by blocking suspicious traffic patterns, such as repeated login failures from the same IP addresses.

Have you considered some Brute Force Detection Tools?


